# unable to print the output in tkinker window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My program is able to print the output in Pycharm, but not the tkinker window. I know I am missing something, but I don't know how to figure out. can you please help me.

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 600

root = tk.Tk()

stockcode = "HAPPSTMNDS"
stock_url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=' + stockcode + '&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0 '
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(stock_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
data_array = soup.find(id='responseDiv').get_text().strip().split(":")
type(data_array)

for item in data_array:
    if 'lastPrice' in item:
        index = data_array.index(item) + 1
        # print("index -->" + str(index))
        lastestprice = data_array[index].split('"')
        # print(data_array)

print(lastestprice[1])

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

label = tk.Label(lower_frame)
label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

How to print the output directly into Tkinter window

Thanks

Comment: Change `label = tk.Label(lower_frame)` to `label = tk.Label(lower_frame, text=lastestprice[1])`? It helps if you reduce your code to the minimal parts of the problem you are trying to solve. In this case, the `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` parts are just noise and could be removed for your example.